# Microsoft Teams Bot - Authenticating Request

Tags: botframework, office365

I have a Microsoft teams bot and I am looking for the best way for me to authenticate incoming requests since I just have an exposed endpoint. Would it be possible to make the incoming requests from Teams to my bot, have custom headers with custom authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement user authentication into your bot to control access to those commands and resources which require access to a specific user's data. Here is the documentation on [user auth in bot builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to get you started.